# my php code doesn't check data with database

Tags: php, mysql

I want this code to check if `$name` and `$password` from form login is in database, if it true it shows `echo "Hello  ".$name;` if not `echo "You are not in database";`, but the problem is it always  shows the truth.

Thanks for your answer and sorry for my english)

```
    include "db.php";
    $db = db();
    /*print_r($db);*/
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $qur = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE name ='".$name."' AND password =  '".$password."'";
    $data_from_table = $db->query($qur);
    if($data_from_table == true)
    {
      echo "Hello  ".$name;
    }
    else
    {
      echo "You are not in database";
    }
```

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. You also should not store passwords in place text.

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation the PDO::Query function returns a `PDOStatement` object or false, if it didn't work well. Why did you was true. [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Why do you check it with true, try checking it with false instead so if it is not false, you can catch your `$name`

Answer (score -1):

$data_from_table  is not true but the result object from the query. But it will be false if the user is not in the db because there is no result.
change it to

```
if($data_from_table!==false) {
```

some well meant advice: never save passwords in real text in databases, i mean like ever. Here is some php function that will get you on track:
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score -2):

1. The new version of mysql in PHP is no longer maintained，use PDO::Query function
2. Check the returned data of `$data_from_table`, is a data set

Comment: `The new version of mysql in PHP is no longer maintained`?? Where is that coming from?

Comment: Excuse i mean mysql query function，use mysqli or PDO whenever possible